Combining LUKS unlock through USB drive and through remote ssh
I have a (LUKS) encrypted root drive and I am able to unlock it either by using a password or a USB drive like it is described here (German wiki): https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Archiv/System_verschl%C3%BCsseln/Entschl%C3%BCsseln_mit_einem_USB-Schl%C3%BCssel/
Since I wanted to be able to also perform a remote unlock I followed another article (German wiki): https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Verschl%C3%BCsseltes_System_via_SSH_freischalten/
However this gives me a error message: "Error: Timeout reached while waiting for askpass."
I figured out that it works just fine when removing the keyscript from crypttab so I guess the problem is the combination of both.
Does anyone have an idea how to approach this issue?
